# Running opencv using java error

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

I have started to learn OpenCV using JAVA language. I tried to run very simple code borrowed from 
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.4-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html

and using the eclipse (JUNO). When I run the following codes

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

//
// Detects faces in an image, draws boxes around them, and writes the results
// to "faceDetection.png".
//
class DetectFaceDemo {
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("\nRunning DetectFaceDemo");

    // Create a face detector from the cascade file in the resources
    // directory.
    CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(getClass().getResource("/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml").getPath());
    Mat image = Highgui.imread(getClass().getResource("/lena.png").getPath());

    // Detect faces in the image.
    // MatOfRect is a special container class for Rect.
    MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
    faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

    System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faceDetections.toArray().length));

    // Draw a bounding box around each face.
    for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
        Core.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
    }

    // Save the visualized detection.
    String filename = "faceDetection.png";
    System.out.println(String.format("Writing %s", filename));
    Highgui.imwrite(filename, image);
  }
}

public class HelloOpenCV {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, OpenCV");

    // Load the native library.
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java245");
    new DetectFaceDemo().run();
  }
}
```

I get

```
Hello, OpenCV

Running DetectFaceDemo
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DetectFaceDemo.run(HelloOpenCV.java:20)
    at HelloOpenCV.main(HelloOpenCV.java:48)
```

where 
**

```
20     CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(getClass().getResource("lbpcascade_frontalface.xml").getPath());
48    new DetectFaceDemo().run();
```

**

I am new in this area and do not know how to get ride of this error. I need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getClass().getResource() loads resources from the classpath and if file is not found it will return null.  So in your case it seems file is not loaded and when you call getPath(), you get null  pointer exception. You need to check that, however you're building, the xml file gets copied over to wherever the class files are compiled to. Or simply make sure that xml file is present in your classpath.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for quick reply you were right. The error is removed but I got this error

<pre>
Hello, OpenCV

Running DetectFaceDemo
Detected 0 faces
Writing faceDetection.png
libpng warning: Image width is zero in IHDR
libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data
</pre>

Comment: One part of the problem is solved by copying the image and XML files to my classpath. However I noticed that the result of running  getClass().getResource("/lena.png").getPath()) contains an extra "/" : "/D:/MFiles/Java/HelloOpenCV/bin/lena.png ". I added a small code to remove the extra slash sign. Something like this str = str.replace("/D:","D:");

Comment: @Hamid Yes that extra slash is a result of some bug fix in jdk. Here you can find more details: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4466485. I am afraid ou will have to do something by yourself to remove that extra slash. Hope your string replace is working fine.

Comment: Can U Share the working line of
Mat image = Highgui.imread.............................

Answer (score 0):

give full path Mat image = Highgui.imread("/Users/test/workspace/OpenCV/bin/lena.png");